# Matplotlib center alignment for pie chart labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, label

I have produced a very simple pie chart in Python using Matplotlib and I am wanting to edit the alignment of my labels. I have used `\n` within my labels to split the line as the labels are too long for one line. But as you can see from the picture called 'pie chart image', it's a mix of weird alignments at the moment. I would really like to have it center alignment.

For other chart/graph types in Matplotlib there is an argument called `align` where you can set it to `center`, however, `plt.pie(...)` does not seem to have this attribute.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
k = [7,15]
labels = 'Strongly and Mostly \n Agree', 'Strongly/Mostly Disagree \n  and In the Middle'
plt.pie(k, labels= labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary of text properties to `plt.pie` via the `textprops` argument. For example:

```
plt.pie(k, labels=labels, textprops={'weight': 'bold'})
```

However, if you try to specify the `horizontalalignment` property, you'll get an error saying that you provided that parameter twice. Obviously *you* didn't, but matplotlib passed both it's hard-coded value and your value to some internal function.

But that's probably a good thing. The way I see it, there's not so much a mix of alignments, but a consistent alignment of the text against the pie.

#### Back to your question

`pie` returns both the patches and the labels for each wedge. So you can loop through the labels after your initial call to `pie` to modify their alignment. That looks like this:

```
k = [7, 15]
labels = 'Strongly and Mostly\nAgree', 'Strongly/Mostly Disagree\nand In the Middle'
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
wedges, labels = ax.pie(k, labels=labels, textprops={'weight': 'bold'})
for label in labels:
    label.set_horizontalalignment('center')
```

[image]

As you can see, the labels now overlap with the wedges, diminishing legibility.

The labels also have a `set_position` method (i.e., `label.set_position((x, y))`), but recomputing the positions for *N* labels in a pie chart sounds like a Bad Time to me.

Comment: Thank you - that's very useful! I don't mind setting positions for only two labels, thanks again :)

Comment: Is it possible to pass `horizontalalignment` as an argument to `ax.pie`? I'm using `pandas`, which doesn't return `wedges` and `labels`; hence the question.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen what happens when you try it?

Comment: `horizontalalignment` is not a valid argument for `DataFrame.plot.pie()` and `Series.plot.pie()`.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen according did you pack it into the `textprops` dictionary?

Comment: @PaulH I just tried adding `textprops={'horizontalalignment': 'center'},` as an argument to `Series.plot.pie()`, but I oddly enough got the error message `TypeError: text() got multiple values for keyword argument 'horizontalalignment'`. I'm giving up on it for now. Please don't waste more of your time on it/me. Thanks though! 